# Mono error : Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, mono, vstest

Have some VStests running on Ubuntu 18.04 using Mono

```
-7cdd897b68-j95rh:/# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.182 (tarball Tue Jun 14 22:29:01 UTC 2022)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        Interpreter:   yes
        LLVM:          yes(610)
        Suspend:       hybrid
        GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

The tests are trying to connect to sharepoint by sending HTTP requests.
However, we get the following error.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /build/mono-6.12.0.182/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  Stack Trace:
     at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00262] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c3] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00102] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00322] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <58d2f9f618534cba97faacbe0f54503d>:0
```

Tried following https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/ and `cert-sync`